# Add/Remove inputs from jQuery array in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add and remove inputs from a form. And then add remove the input values from an array that I can eventually POST.

The input additions and removes are fine. But I cannot get the array to print the new values(?)

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
  var encdom_local = ['something'];

  $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt"  name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="NETWORK/[IP/CIDR]" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    encdom_local.push(1);
    i++;
    return false;
  });
  $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
    if( i > 2 ) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });

  $(".result").html(encdom_local.join(""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="p_scents">
  <p>
    <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="NETWORK/[IP/CIDR]" /></label>
    <a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a>
  </p>
  <p class="result"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean by print is this line of your code:

```
$(".result").html(encdom_local.join(""));
```

then it 'happens' only once, after you add your event listeners. If u want to print it every time, just add this printing method to the `.live()` events.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(".result").text(encdom_local.join(""));
```

Comment: Try this? Why? What does it do? How does it solve the problem?